# xamppでphpをデプロイできません、xampが機能してくれません

Tags: php, xampp

windowsでxamppが機能してくれません。

windowsのバーチャルホストにてphpデプロイテストをしたいのですが、

windowsにxamppを導入し

apache（81port）、mysql(3306port)を起動し

起動urlは `http://locathost:81` とし、
アクセスするのですが以下のような画面になり、xampが機能していないことがわかります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Apache(Webサーバー)の「httpd.conf」ファイルのディレクトリ設定は

xamppをなぜ正常に起動できないのか、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 「以下の画面」や「ファイルのディレクトリは」の説明に当たる画像やコードが添付されていないようです。質問は後からでも [編集] できるので追記してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

ドキュメントルートの下にコンテンツが配置してあるかを確認して、ブラウザで (対象のファイルに) アクセスしてみてください。

XAMPP 環境でのドキュメントルートは Windows の場合、`C:\xampp\htdocs\` などになります。

---

- `http:/localhost/` 等のようにファイル名を指定しないアクセスの場合、 `index.html` 等のファイルを探しに行きます。
- `index.html` が見つかればその内容を表示し、これも見つからなければディレクトリの一覧を表示する機能が Apache にはあります。
- ただし「ディレクトリの一覧を表示する」機能はセキュリティ上の理由により設定でオフにする場合もあり、画面に表示されているのはディレクトリの一覧表示が禁止された状態だと推測されます。

Webサーバ (Apache) 自体は正常に動作していると思うので、表示すべきコンテンツが配置されているかをまず確認してください。
これとは別に、PHPを正常に動作させるための設定変更が必要となるかもしれません。

Comment: XAMPP 環境でのドキュメントルート,C:\xampp\htdocs\にindex.htmlを置いてるのですが見に行ってくれず画像のようになります。再インストールしてもただいま治る気配がありません。

Comment: `httpd.conf` の中身を質問文に追記してみてください。